# Why does terraform plan fail with 'Error: Clean path required'

Tags: terraform

I am developing some terraform modules and as such am often doing `terraform apply` then `terraform destroy`.

Sometimes as i'm making changes to main.tf files and attempt to subsequently execute any of `terraform apply`, `terraform destroy` or `terraform plan` I get the error message

> 'Error: Clean path required'
>
> [SOME MODULE SPECIFIC DETAILS]
>
> Replace value with [SOME PATH] to avoid resource replacement.

I'm fairly inexperienced with terraform but I can't find any references to this anywhere.

Can anyone tell me why it happens, what its trying to tell me, and how I can debug/fix/avoid it please?

I've had this several times and seem to end up going around a loop of removing the state files, and re executing plan/apply/destroy commands until eventually it starts to work. I have no explanation for why or how, but it's frustrating and time consuming :)

Comment: It's not clear for me, you destroy all, do a change to the `main.tf` and after you run again the plan/apply? What are you changing?

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you've described [seems to come from the `databricks/databricks` provider](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/bd05be25f14fb66bfadbd30c020ade23f891baf8/workspace/file_resource.go#L163-L173):

```
                clean := filepath.ToSlash(filepath.Clean(v))
                if v != clean {
                    return diag.Diagnostics{
                        {
                            Summary: "Clean path required",
                            Detail: fmt.Sprintf(
                                "Replace value with %s to avoid resource replacement",
                                clean),
                            Severity:      diag.Error,
                            AttributePath: p,
                        },
                    }
                }
```

The provider seems to want you to pass a path that uses only forward slashes (no backslashes) and that doesn't include any `../` or `./` segments. This decision was made by the developers of that provider, and the commit where that code was added doesn't include any explanation, so I cannot say for certain why it is implemented this way, but I can speculate.

The error message says "to avoid resource replacement" and so I assume the idea here is to force you to write a path in a canonical way so that writing the same path in a different way later won't create ambiguity about whether your new path is equivalent or not.

For example, if you write `foo/./bar` and then later change it to `foo/bar` then on all operating systems where Terraform can run today those two paths are semantically equivalent despite being written differently. Perhaps the provider is unable to determine whether two path strings are equivalent and so the developers instead decided to just force you to write a canonical path.

Provider developers can potentially solve this problem in a slightly different way by defining a rule for deciding whether two values are semantically equal. If the provider developers had done that instead then the provider would be able to accept paths written in a non-canonical way but would treat a new path as the same if its cleaned version is equivalent. I assume there was some special circumstance with this provider that caused the developers to choose to make this an error rather than a custom equality rule.

The provider is relying on a Go function called `filepath.Clean` to create a "clean" version of the provided path, and so with the provider as currently written the only way to make it work would be to write the path exactly how the error message tells you to write it, immediately after the words "Replace path with".

If this behavior doesn't seem correct for your understanding of how Databricks works, you could perhaps open an issue in [the GitHub repository for this provider](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks) to discuss the details with the provider development team.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this up. I had not realised the error messages were coming from the provider. I had wrongly assumed this was a generic terraform message. (Hence not finding anything online! )

This answers the question perfectly - databricks is the provider i'm working with, and path changes were causing the issue. 

Many Thanks

Comment: It might interest you to know that I found out the databricks provider was involved by [searching for this message in GitHub Code Search](https://cs.github.com/?scopeName=All+repos&scope=&q=%22Clean+path+required%22). That doesn't always work because sometimes error messages are too generic for the results to be useful, but in this case all of the results were from either this provider's main repository or forks of that repository.